# What, if any, is the significance of "Wabash and Lake"?

Tags: the-matrix, supernatural

I had to rewind when I heard it, but Supernatural ("Salvation", S1:E21) referenced Wabash and Lake, which I recognized from The Matrix. From the Supernatural [Wiki](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/1.21_Salvation):

> **Meg:** There's a warehouse in Lincoln, on the corner of Wabash and Lake. You're gonna meet me there.
>
> *Wabash and Lake is the location of the [Heart O' The City Hotel](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Heart_O%27_The_City_Hotel) at [Mega City](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Mega_City) in [The Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix).*

From [matrixfans.net](https://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix/transcript/)'s transcript page for the Matrix:

> Neo: Mr. Wizard, get me the hell out of here.
>
> Tank: Got a patch on an old exit, Wabash and Lake.

From what I can tell, at least a couple movies were also filmed ([Transformers 3](https://transformerslive.blogspot.com/2010/08/tf3-chicago-wabash-and-lake-set-pics.html), [Rampage](https://www.nbcchicago.com/news/local/the-rock-dwayne-johnson-movie-filming-close-downtown-chicago-streets/16820/)) on/around "Wabash and Lake" in Chicago. The Matrix, according to [movie-locations.com](https://www.movie-locations.com/movies/m/Matrix.php), also used Chicago as a reference but did not film there.

**Does Wabash and Lake have a special significance in Supernatural or the Matrix? Does it have a general cinematic significance in Hollywood? If so, what is the significance of Wabash and Lake?**

Comment: The show Supernatural made a ton of popular culture references deliberately right through. In-universe the Winchesters watched all the big TV and movie titles and Meg would be aware. If it sounded like a joke on The Matrix it was probably meant to be just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume The Matrix reference is the first, because the various locations in the movie are based in Chicago where the Wachowskis grew up.

Wabash runs north-south through the downtown and ends down around 115th St. Lake runs east-west in a line just south of Chicago River exit into Michigan. The two meet [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/N+Wabash+Ave+%26+E+Lake+St,+Chicago,+IL+60601,+USA/@41.8857624,-87.6284726,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x880e2caf83095805:0x3bfc5e7f74a6884b!8m2!3d41.8857584!4d-87.6262839) under the el.

I haven't been there, but looking in Google reveals no reason why anyone else would select it. So I further assume the other references are simply name dropping The Matrix because, well, why not?